# How to run two components in Event dispatch thread at the same time?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have a JButton that when i click on it, i load some data from a database + initialize a JDialog that has many controls + fill those controls with the loaded data then show that slow JDialog. This takes about 3 to 5 seconds to finally show the JDialog, which causes the program to freeze in a bad manner.

I have created a small JDialog with a JXBusyLabel from SwingX to show a busy label while loading and initializing such slow processes. But how can i run this busy label JDialog in the EDT while initializing the slow dialog ?

*Note: Loading the data from the db is not slow, but initializing the heavy JDialog and its components causes that slow processing.*

Comment: shouldn't happen ... how many controls, roughly? Can you show a code snippet demonstrating how you build/fill the slow dialog?

Comment: @kleopatra: It actually freezes from 3 to 5 seconds. I have edited this in the question. The JDialog contains a JTabbedPane with 7 tabs + some JLabels, JButtons inside each tab, and some JXColorSelectionButton from SwingX ... I guess the color buttons cause that slow performance.

Comment: guessing is not enough ;-) If you're sure it's the colorSelectionButton, please file an issue in swingx issue tracker (preferably with a small runnable example so we can reproduce it)

Comment: @kleopatra: There is another thing ... In each tab i have a comboBox where i load in it all operating system fonts ... When i disabled this, things were loading faster.

Comment: just to get it clear: the slow loading was all (?) due to loading the fonts? (which sounds reasonable, even native win explorer takes its time on opening the font folder, if I remember correctly)

Comment: @kleopatra: Okay, that takes us to the first point .. Loading the big dialog is still slow :)

Comment: but now you know the reason - and already have the fix (load the fonts in a background thread, as suggested by two answers)

Comment: @kleopatra: Sorry, you are right ... Sometimes i need someone to knock over my head to get the idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Show the busy dialog.
2. Start [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and do all long-running tasks in the background (database)
3. When done, create big dialog with data from database (inside SwingWorker.done( method))
4. Hide busy dialog, show big dialog.

Comment: I have done that, the busy label dialog appears but it is freezing(The busy label does not run), until the big dialog appears !

Comment: Are you running the database operations in the background thread? You should put this code inside `SwingWorker.doInBackground()` method

Comment: you can add PropertyChangeListener() to SwingWorker

Answer (score 0):

You should better use SwingWorker:

1. create the dialog with busy label, create the swing worker
2. start the swingworker (it will asynchronously load data from DB, prepare control for the main dialog)
3. in SwingWorker's done() method, hide your first small dialog and show the main one